# Aspectj @Before works but @Pointcut does not

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

I have a simple example of an aspectj implementation in a spring boot app and I'm trying to get each different method working.

If I use the following

```
  @Before("execution(* com.example.test.controllers.ProductController.deleteProduct(..))")
  public void specificInterception() {
    System.out.println("pointcut interception working");
  }
```

This works fine, and I can see a console output of the `println`

However, if I use

```
  @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.test.controllers.ProductController.deleteProduct(..))")
  public void specificInterception() {
    System.out.println("pointcut interception working");
  }
```

It fails to trigger. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method annotated with `@Pointcut` on its own doesn't do anything. It only allows you re-use the same expression multiple times rather than having to redeclare it. I'm not even sure if the method body of such a method will be invoked.

In your case, you can use your pointcut like this:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.example.test.controllers.ProductController.deleteProduct(..))")
public void specificPointcut() {}


@Before("specificPointcut()")
public void specificInterception() {
    System.out.println("pointcut interception working");
}
```